# has been modified, but is still open elsewhere with identical changes. Closing this will not lose those changes. Save anyway?

Tags: java, eclipse, save

I want to know why this message alert when I run a Java project:

[image]

I use Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

This dialog will be shown

- when you have the **same file open in two or more editors** of different kind **sharing the same content** (whether they share the same content depends on their implementation; e.g. the Java editor and the Compare editor) and
- when there are **unsaved changes** and
- when one editor will be **closed or** something will be **launched** with the preference *Save required dirty editors before launching* (which is enabled by default; see preferences *Run/Debug > Launching*)

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a file `sample.txt`
2. Right-click `sample.txt` and choose *Open With > **Text Editor***
3. Right-click `sample.txt` and choose *Open With > **Generic Text Editor***
4. **Make a change** in one of the editors, e.g. enter the text `hi`, which results that both editors will show the change and become dirty (editor tab will be prefixed with `*`)
5. **Close one** of the two editors